# I need to decrease the size of the header background color

Tags: css

How can i decrease the size of the header in the logo class? My logo contains the name " PIED PIEPR". But the background image is quite big in the header. I tried decreasing with height attribute but didnt work.

```
Style Sheet:

    body{
        margin: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .container{
        position: relative;
        height: 50px;
        width: 1100px;
    }

    .masthead{
        background: #4fc3f7;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        position: fixed;
        color: white;
    }

    .logo{
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        left: 90px;
        font-family: Josefin Slab;
        font-size: 21px;

    }

    a:link    {color: white;  text-decoration: none; }
    a:visited {color: white;  text-decoration: none; }
    a:hover   {color: white;  text-decoration: none; }
    a:active  {color: white;  text-decoration: none; }

    li{
        position: relative;
        left: 155px;
        list-style: none;
        font-family: Raleway;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 21px; 
        padding-top: 20px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .navigation{
        float: right;
    }

Markup"

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Home Page</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainpage.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="masthead">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo"><h1><a href="#">CRUX</a></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="navigation">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Institution</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">|| Sign In</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>    
                </ul>

            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container"> 
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p> </p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show JS Fiddle please

Comment: I only have the markup.

Comment: So what is your actual need

Comment: do you want to reduce your header height that what you want

Comment: I want to decrease the background color height

Comment: Can you reproduce with some images to represent it. Guess I am not getting you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your `h1` will hold a default `margin` value all you have to make them `0`. Just add the following style to your `css`

```
h1{
    margin:0;
}
```

**OR**

```
*{
    margin:0;
}
```

**NOTE**: You will still find little space on top and bottom thats because of the `line-height` property you can also reduce them to fit your logo exactly to your `background-color`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/yfqzrrv8/)**